# URLClassLoader is unable to load class in java

Tags: java, urlclassloader

I am trying to compile a java source file using the `javac` and command line and i want to load it dynamically at runtime using the URLClassLoader but it fails.

My Steps:

1. This is the java source file:

```
package ubl4nk;

import model.User; // <------- This is imported from lib1.jar which i will include in the next step
import runner.Activity; // <------- This is imported from lib2.jar which i will include in the next step

public class Equity {
    
    public void function1() {
           // ...
    }
    
    public void function2() {
           // ...
    }
        
}
```

2. I run this command `javac -classpath lib1.jar;lib2.jar Equity.java` and then i get an output `Equity.class` file.
3. I create a jar file from `Equity.class` using command `jar -cf myjar.jar *.class` and i get the output `myjar.jar`
4. I want to load the `Equity` class in my program but it throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ubl4nk.Equity`:

```
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{
            new File("C:\\Users\\FX506HC\\Desktop\\mtest\\lib1.jar").toURI().toURL(),
            new File("C:\\Users\\FX506HC\\Desktop\\mtest\\lib2.jar").toURI().toURL(),
            new File("C:\\Users\\FX506HC\\Desktop\\mtest\\myjar.jar").toURI().toURL()
        };

        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class cls = cl.loadClass("ubl4nk.Equity");
        System.out.println(cls.getName());
```

Comment: The `jar` command you shown here won't setup packages correctly, have you checked that `myjar.jar` contains `ubl4nk/Equity.class`? Test the jars first.

Comment: @DuncG Yes you are right, i missed that the jar should contains the same structure as package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
jar -cf myjar.jar *.class
```

The created jar does not include the `nbl4nk` folder. It only includes the `Equity` class, sitting at the root directory of the jar. Without the `nbl4nk` folder, a `URLClassLoader` cannot find the `nbl4nk` package, and hence cannot find `nbl4nk.Equity`.

Assuming the class file is actually in a folder called `nbl4nk`, you should instead include the whole folder:

```
jar -cf myjar.jar .
```

You can also go up a directory, and run

```
jar -cf myjar.jar nbl4nk
```